# Mean-field approximation of the disordered state of Heisenberg model

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body

Consider a 1D ferromagnetic Heisenberg model with the Hamiltonian 
$$\mathcal H=-J\sum_i \vec S_i\cdot \vec S_{i+1}.$$
For $|\vec S|=\frac{1}{2}$, we have the usual fermionic representation
$\vec S_i=\frac{1}{2}f^\dagger _{i\alpha} \vec \sigma_{\alpha\beta}f_{i\beta}$.

In the ordered phase at low temperature, one can obtain a mean-field approximation of the Hamiltonian by using the order parameter $\langle S^z_i\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\langle f^\dagger_{i\uparrow}f_{i\uparrow}-f^\dagger_{i\downarrow}f_{i\downarrow}  \rangle$, which can be determined self-consistently.

However, in the disordered phase at high temperature, the mean-field Hamiltonian vanishes if we use the same order parameter. What order parameter(s) can one use to obtain a better approximation?

Comment: Why should there be an order parameter useful for describing the disordered phase?

Comment: @MarkMitchison While the magnetization at each site is zero in the disordered phase, there may still be correlation between different sites. Perhaps such correlation can be used as an order parameter? In any case, I would expect there to be a better approximation than a vanishing Hamiltonian.

Comment: I don't see how you could use correlations as an order parameter in the context of mean-field theory. The essence of mean-field theory is neglecting the correlated fluctuations of the spins. This works in the ordered phase because most of the spins are aligned, so the fluctuations are negligible compared to the macroscopic mean field. In a completely disordered phase the mean-field Hamiltonian *should* vanish: the average field is zero. This amounts to assuming that the equilibrium state is a completely unpolarised (infinite temperature) state $\rho \sim 1$. Apologies if you understood this.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate thermal averages or dynamics?

Comment: @MarkMitchison Thanks for the explanation on mean-field theory. I am interested in the dynamics, in particular the spin susceptibility. So, I would need something more than a vanishing Hamiltonian.

Comment: I don't know whether analytical techniques for this sort of problem are known. The system is exactly diagonalisable in principle by Bethe Ansatz. I don't think you can feasibly get correlation functions this way, though. Numerically the problem is extremely straightforward using the TEBD algorithm (time-dependent DMRG). See, for example, [White & Affleck, arXiv:0712.3785](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.3785). If you don't have access to TEBD code my group is developing an [open-source version](http://ccpforge.cse.rl.ac.uk/gf/project/tntlibrary/) that you can probably use if you ask nicely.